# 0x8000000e error when calling onsuggestionsrequested (win8)

Tags: javascript, search, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to program a search contract in my windows 8 app. basically everythings just works as it should, except the suggestion list.
Always when i enter the function, where i should add my suggestions i get the runtime error 0x8000000e

I just copy pasted the code from the examples, with the only difference, that i load my data from the database.

```
appModel.Search.SearchPane.getForCurrentView().onsuggestionsrequested = function (eventObject) {
    var queryText = eventObject.queryText, suggestionRequest = eventObject.request;
    var query = queryText.toLowerCase();
    var maxNumberOfSuggestions = 5;
    mkData.getWords(eventObject.queryText, maxNumberOfSuggestions, function (suggestionList) {
        for (var i = 0, len = suggestionList.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (suggestionList[i].substr(0, query.length).toLowerCase() === query) {
                suggestionRequest.searchSuggestionCollection.appendQuerySuggestion(suggestionList[i]);
                if (suggestionRequest.searchSuggestionCollection.size === maxNumberOfSuggestions) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    if (suggestionRequest.searchSuggestionCollection.size > 0) {
        WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Suggestions provided for query: " + queryText, "sample", "status");
    } else {
        WinJS.log && WinJS.log("No suggestions provided for query: " + queryText, "sample", "status");
    }
};
```

if i exchange the Ajax-Call with an static array of suggestions, it works :(
in the suggestion list are good words.

I already found solutions for this, but only in C#. There the developer must add the await keyword, but in javascript i dont have this.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i solved it now on my own. here the solution. you have to use the Deferral. Its hardly documented :(

```
appModel.Search.SearchPane.getForCurrentView().onsuggestionsrequested = function (eventObject) {
    var queryText = eventObject.queryText, suggestionRequest = eventObject.request;
    var maxNumberOfSuggestions = 5;
    var deferral = eventObject.request.getDeferral();
    mkData.getWords(queryText, maxNumberOfSuggestions, function (suggestionList) {
        suggestionRequest.searchSuggestionCollection.appendQuerySuggestions(suggestionList);
        deferral.complete();
    });
    if (suggestionRequest.searchSuggestionCollection.size > 0) {
        WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Suggestions provided for query: " + queryText, "sample", "status");
    } else {
        WinJS.log && WinJS.log("No suggestions provided for query: " + queryText, "sample", "status");
    }
};
```